# Publish Settings - Publishing Failed

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-1.7

Publish Settings - Publishing Failed

publishing error: An error occurred while generating the semantic schema for Schema 'xxx' (tcm:xx-xxx-8).

Root element is missing.

TemplateBuilder error:

```
Debugging was started in process 'TcmTemplateDebugHost' with id 2908
PublishMappings: Added JSON Binary '/Preview/us/system/mappings/vocabularies.json' related to Component 'Core' (tcm:xx-xxxz) with variant ID 'vocabularies'
An error occurred while generating the semantic schema for Schema 'xxx' (tcm:xx-xxxx-8-v0).
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.PublishMappings.GetSemanticSchema(Schema schema)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.PublishMappings.PublishSemanticSchemas(StructureGroup structureGroup, Component relatedComponent)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.PublishMappings.Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.AssemblyMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.RunTemplate(Engine engine, Package package, String templateUri, String className)
   at Tridion.Templating.CSharpTemplate.CSharpSourceTemplate.Transform(Engine __engine, Package __package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformItem(Template template, IdentifiableObject itemToRender)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebuggingEngine.Run()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebugSession.Run()
---Caused by:
Root element is missing.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(String text, LoadOptions options)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.PublishMappings.GetSemanticTypes(Schema schema)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.PublishMappings.GetSemanticSchema(Schema schema)
```

**why root element is missing from this XML?**

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="uuid:a1553e13-3f82-4e62-ae15-99986b90fcc6" xmlns:tcmi="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/Instance" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="uuid:a1553e13-3f82-4e62-ae15-99986b90fcc6">
      <xsd:import namespace="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/Instance"></xsd:import>
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
          <tcm:Labels xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
            <tcm:Label ElementName="aToZListingType" Metadata="false">Listing Type for the A-Z component (Products/Solutions/InfoCenter) </tcm:Label>
          </tcm:Labels>
        </xsd:appinfo>
      </xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:element name="atozListing">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="aToZListingType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
              <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:appinfo>
                  <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
                    <configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit">
                      <field>
                        <editable>false</editable>
                      </field>
                    </configuration>
                  </tcm:ExtensionXml>
                  <tcm:Size xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">1</tcm:Size>
                  <tcm:listtype xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">select</tcm:listtype>
                </xsd:appinfo>
              </xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:normalizedString">
                  <xsd:enumeration value="viewAllProducts"></xsd:enumeration>
                  <xsd:enumeration value="viewAllSolutions"></xsd:enumeration>
                  <xsd:enumeration value="viewAllInfo"></xsd:enumeration>
                </xsd:restriction>
              </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
```

Comment: hi Nick, XML is copied above, root element is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is resolved after removing the app_id "http://www.sdl.com/tridion/SemanticMapping/typeof"

Use provided Powershell commandlet to remove the app_id, for example:
remove-tcmapplicationData -TcmApplicationIds http://www.sdl.com/tridion/SemanticMapping/typeof

Answer (score 2):

I’ve had a problem in the past with Tridion putting ‘-v0’ on the end of tcmIds when the item it checked-out (even if it’s an old schema with a long version history). I suspect that this is a bug in the product.

Can you make sure that the schema is checked in and try again?

This may be a red herring, but I lost hours to it, so thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: thanks Jonathan, the schema is checked in. and i also deleted -v0 version. issue not solved.

Answer (score 2):

Note that those Stack Traces provide a lot of valuable information to analyze where the problem lies. See also https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/b/blog-posts/posts/digital-forensics-based-on-a-stack-trace

In this particular case, the exception occurs when parsing XML in `Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.PublishMappings.GetSemanticTypes(Schema schema)`

The implementation of that method can be found here: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/release/1.7/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates/Templates/PublishMappings.cs

Note that the XML being parsed in that method is **not** the Schema XSD, but the content of DXA Application Data used to specify the Semantic Type(s) of a Schema (Application ID: `http://www.sdl.com/tridion/SemanticMapping/typeof`)

This (optional) App Data is expected to be XML, but looking at the exception message, it seems to be an empty string or plain text.

Not sure how you got to such malformed DXA App Data and whether you expect it to be present in the first place. If not, you could purge the App Data using `Remove-TcmApplicationData`. See https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-FBFAD6E3-19D4-4A86-AC6C-A21006C94084

Comment: thanks Rick :), is it safe to Purge the App Data?

Comment: The Semantic Mapping App Data is normally not used. It is an advanced mapping option. See https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-7EA7470E-1592-4734-B824-8F23FF3BD526

Comment: thanks Rick this fixed the issue