# DXA 2.2 "Schema Id must not be null" using dynamic component template

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, sites-9.1

DXA 2.2 "Schema Id must not be null" using dynamic component template.

```
{
   "Id":"193303-193302",
   "Namespace":"tcm",
   "ComponentTemplate":{
      "Id":"193302",
      "Namespace":"tcm",
      "Title":"ESB",
      "RevisionDate":"2020-04-28T13:59:34.79",
      "OutputFormat":"HTML Fragment",
      "Metadata":{
         "view":"ESB"

}

},
   "Folder":{
      "Id":"8540",
      "Title":"Content"

},
   "Content":{
      "PlanText":"test dxa 2.2 esb Dynamic"

},
   "MvcData":{
      "ViewName":"ESB"

},
   "XpmMetadata":{
      "ComponentID":"tcm:83-193303",
      "ComponentModified":"2020-04-23T15:50:57.253",
      "ComponentTemplateID":"tcm:83-193302-32",
      "ComponentTemplateModified":"2020-04-28T13:59:34.79",
      "IsRepositoryPublished":true

},
   "SchemaId":"193301"
}
```

The website shows "Schema Id must not be null"

However, the static component template with the same component renders fine. what's missing in the dynamic component template? thanks!

adding--------------------------------------------------------

the propose is rendering with a dynamic component template with DXA 2.2

site log:

```
2020-04-28 10:12:32,825 [84] ERROR - Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: Schema Id must not be null.
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.LocalizationMappingsManager.GetSemanticSchema(String schemaId) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Common\Configuration\LocalizationMappingsManager.cs:line 62
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.Localization.GetSemanticSchema(String schemaId) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Common\Configuration\Localization.cs:line 315
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Mapping.SemanticMapping.GetSchema(String id, Localization loc) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Common\Mapping\SemanticMapping.cs:line 70
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildEntityModel(EntityModel& entityModel, EntityModelData entityModelData, Type baseModelType, Localization localization) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 174
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.ModelBuilderPipeline.CreateEntityModel(EntityModelData entityModelData, Type baseModelType, Localization localization) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\ModelBuilderPipeline.cs:line 157
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.CreateRegionModel(RegionModelData regionModelData, Localization localization) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 876
Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: Schema Id must not be null.
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.LocalizationMappingsManager.GetSemanticSchema(String schemaId) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Common\Configuration\LocalizationMappingsManager.cs:line 62
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.Localization.GetSemanticSchema(String schemaId) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Common\Configuration\Localization.cs:line 315
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Mapping.SemanticMapping.GetSchema(String id, Localization loc) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Common\Mapping\SemanticMapping.cs:line 70
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildEntityModel(EntityModel& entityModel, EntityModelData entityModelData, Type baseModelType, Localization localization) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 174
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.ModelBuilderPipeline.CreateEntityModel(EntityModelData entityModelData, Type baseModelType, Localization localization) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\ModelBuilderPipeline.cs:line 157
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.CreateRegionModel(RegionModelData regionModelData, Localization localization) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 876
2020-04-28 10:12:33,088 [84] ERROR - Error initializing the ContextServiceClaimsProvider.
2020-04-28 10:13:29,541 [69] ERROR - Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: Schema Id must not be null.
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.LocalizationMappingsManager.GetSemanticSchema(String schemaId) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Common\Configuration\LocalizationMappingsManager.cs:line 62
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.Localization.GetSemanticSchema(String schemaId) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Common\Configuration\Localization.cs:line 315
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Mapping.SemanticMapping.GetSchema(String id, Localization loc) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Common\Mapping\SemanticMapping.cs:line 70
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildEntityModel(EntityModel& entityModel, EntityModelData entityModelData, Type baseModelType, Localization localization) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 174
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.ModelBuilderPipeline.CreateEntityModel(EntityModelData entityModelData, Type baseModelType, Localization localization) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\ModelBuilderPipeline.cs:line 157
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.CreateRegionModel(RegionModelData regionModelData, Localization localization) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 876
Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: Schema Id must not be null.
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.LocalizationMappingsManager.GetSemanticSchema(String schemaId) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Common\Configuration\LocalizationMappingsManager.cs:line 62
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.Localization.GetSemanticSchema(String schemaId) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Common\Configuration\Localization.cs:line 315
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Mapping.SemanticMapping.GetSchema(String id, Localization loc) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Common\Mapping\SemanticMapping.cs:line 70
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildEntityModel(EntityModel& entityModel, EntityModelData entityModelData, Type baseModelType, Localization localization) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 174
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.ModelBuilderPipeline.CreateEntityModel(EntityModelData entityModelData, Type baseModelType, Localization localization) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\ModelBuilderPipeline.cs:line 157
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.CreateRegionModel(RegionModelData regionModelData, Localization localization) in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 876
2020-04-28 10:13:29,624 [69] ERROR - Error initializing the ContextServiceClaimsProvider.
2020-04-28 10:18:04,669 [77] ERROR - Error initializing the ContextServiceClaimsProvider.
```

Comment: Could you please update your question with full trace logs?, also explain bit more detail on your implementation what exactly you are doing and getting this errror message?

Comment: Did you do a Publish Settings + Admin Refresh after adding the template? Also, see https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20843/publish-settings-publishing-failed it might be related

Comment: Check the DXA Page JSON you get back from the (GraphQL) Content Service (assuming you’re using the Content Service with DXA Model Extension, rather than the DXA Model Service).

Comment: hi Rick, Yes i am using content service, somehow the CP id is 193303-193302, so DXA cannot get the correct model?

Comment: The '193303-193302' is a composite ID consisting of the ComponentId + TemplateId. The Model Extension (of the Content Service) should expand it automatically and include the appropriate EntityModel into your PageModel

Comment: thanks Atila, not sure why i am getting this error. with content service. static component template getting correct entitymodel

Comment: Please check/provide the Page JSON as returned by the Content Service. As Atila says, the DCP should be expanded in the Page JSON. If that is not the case, you may have forgotten to install the DXA Model Extension.

Comment: @LucasLiu, I am facing the same issue. Have you managed to fix this? Wondering what could be the reason and what's the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Rick mentioned dxa model extension wasn't installed. after install dxa model extension solved this issue. thanks Rick quick answer.