# DXA view throwing error "Schema ID must not be null"

Tags: dxa, content-delivery, dxa-2.0, extension-model

I am facing one weird issue where one of DXA view start throwing error after deployment. Once we publish the page and restart the content service, it start working. It seems similar to this issue [DXA 2.2 "Schema Id must not be null" using dynamic component template](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20903/dxa-2-2-schema-id-must-not-be-null-using-dynamic-component-template). On the page other views are rendering fine which has static component templates associated. Only issue is with this dynamic component presentation. Also if I create a page containing only this dynamic component presentation it's also rendering fine. We have model service extension installed by uploading it to CMS Add-On and I can see content service having folder with all Jars required for model service extension.

Below error message showing:

[image]

I can see this error message mentioned in the DXA framework codebase and suspecting this might be related to timeout while fetching heavy content from model service extension. Wondering if anyone seen this error before and suggest what could be the reason here. Thanks in advance.

**Update**: It seems old observation that restarting content service resolved the issue was not correct. While further debugging we found that dynamic component presentation is having blank record in broker database.

Comment: What’s the Stack Trace (in the log file)?

Comment: Is the DXA Model Extension properly installed? Do include pages work properly?

Comment: @RickPannekoek include pages are working fine. Even the page showing the error also work fine, only some times it start throwing error. This issue is in production staging environment where we have log level set to Error. To my surprise, there was no significant log except this message in App as well as in Content service. When I changed the log level to debug and restart the app pool, I was not able to reproduce the error again. This issue occurs only some time. We notice it mostly after deployment.

Comment: had this issue before need to install dxa model extension

Comment: Hi @LucasLiu We have model service extension installed. I have checked the folder with Jars available inside content service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some further debugging we found that few DCPs stored in broker database has no content(Empty value) and leads to the know issue with DXA 2.2 here https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000011590.

Comment: Glad you found what the issue was. As the original reporter of said bug (experienced it in DXA 2.1), I can indeed confirm that since it's a tricky one to discover/troubleshoot, it's a big pain in the A. As for the fix, if you can't upgrade fully to DXA 2.2, the issue is in the Templating code and you can apply only that piece of code.

Comment: Thanks @AtilaSos. Yeah, we have applied only the changes in templating code.